# Why is /dev/kvm access restricted by default?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, kvm

When searching the net for the problem of unprivileged `kvm` failing to access `/dev/kvm`, you can see lots of posts recommending one of these:

- `adduser $youruser kvm` (adding your user to the `kvm` group)
- Changing the permission of the device to `666`
- Changing the owner of the device

If this was the universally right answer, we'd just change the defaults and be done rather than having everyone changing theirs individually. So there must be a reason to have restricted permissions on `/dev/kvm` by default.

A partial answer is that access to this device increases the attack surface on the Linux kernel, e.g. [CVE-2021-22543](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2021-22543). Restricting access clearly is a hardening measure. For similar reasons, Debian and RedHat used to deny unprivileged user namespaces by default, but these have been relaxed now that user namespaces have matured.

Are there more reasons to restrict access? Is there a trivial way to expand `/dev/kvm` access to root privileges on patched kernels?

Comment: Questions like "**why** <some feature> is implemented <in some way>" are rarely fit for Stack Overflow: Only developers (or even managers) knows the reason, others may only **guess** about the reasonings. You may ask, however, about concrete implications of an implementation. See that meta question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323005/are-why-questions-allowed.

Comment: While the question title matches the generic template, its content expands and poses two sub-questions that are unrelated to opinions. As such I believe that this is on-topic.

Comment: By "two sub-questions" do you mean the question "Is there a trivial way to expand `/dev/kvm` access to root privileges on patched kernels?" and its "partial anwer" about CVE? Yes, that question could constitute a (seemingly good) question post. But the current title makes the question post confusing...

Comment: You are much better off asking this kind of question on the Kernel newbies or KVM mailing lists.